# .NET Linq implementation in Javascript with DefinitelyTyped TypeScript definitions

Tags: library, javascript, .net

I'm looking for an implementation of .NET Linq in Javascript that includes DefinitelyTyped TypeScript definitions.

I've already tested some tools below; however, each is either written in an older version of TypeScript which throws a bunch of errors or they don't have DefinitelyTyped definitions built in:

- InfoQ
- [JavascriptLinq](http://www.javascriptlinq.com/)
- [LinqJS](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Such a simple question and it got downvoted

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Software Recommendations, while it may be a simple question, we tend to add as much detail as possibly to a question in order to receive the best answers possible. Could you add more information such as what specifically you're looking for? Please check out our [Question Quality Guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/133) and edit your question accordingly, thanks:).

Comment: Made an edit to improve formatting, including example of already tested libraries helps, could you also include if you need it to be gratis or if commercial is ok?

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/dibiancoj/Linq4Javascript

It uses iterators for lazy evaluation. I use it in a number of projects with no complaints at all. A pretty solid project.